# Select Specific Element of String In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, extjs, explode

I dont know what can i do to get specific word in a string. This is my string:

```
$productList = "A, Two Way A(TA)-(BWY DL), B, Multispeed Network-(BA_G)";
```

I got this string from checkbox on tree panel in ExtJs. That string will be exploded to be like this:

```
Array(
[0]=>BWY DL
[1]=>BA_G
)
```

I used explode, but the result is not right.

```
Array ( 
[0] => A, Two Way A(TA 
[1] => 
[2] => BWY DL 
[3] => , B, Multispeed Network 
[4] => BA_G
[5] => 
)
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: what you need is not clear to me , do you need all the chars within parentheses `()` or something else ?

Comment: Well, then just pull out everything you need from the exploded array: `$wanted = [$exploded[2], $exploded[4]];` - or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Quasdunk that's right, but if there's more data.. i can't put it one by one like $wanted = [$exploded[2], $exploded[4]]; <br> how if it can be more array data?

Comment: @Lekhnath no, i just want it show **BWY DL** and **BA_G** only

Comment: @NikeAngreni Ok, but then you'll need to explain a little more how the input data looks like (is it always the same string, or which parts vary) and which parts exactly you need to extract. And what exactly do you mean by "there can be more array data"?

Comment: @Quasdunk the string i got from json data of extjs tree panel value.. so i checked one or many checkbox it will became json data that separated by **,**(comma)

Comment: @NikeAngreni I don't think it really matters where the data comes from. The question is: Which parts do you need to extract out of it? By which criteria? Do you need all the string in brackets? Do you need the first string after a hyphen? What is it? I don't think we can help you if you don't tell us what you need! I gave a solution to your example in my comment above, but I don't know about further criteria!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$productList = "A, Two Way A(TA)-(BWY DL), B, Multispeed Network-(BA_G)";

$patt = '/\-\(([A-z ]*)\)/'; // match all which starts from -( and ends with )

preg_match_all($patt, $productList, $match);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($match[1]);
```

I am not still clear whether you are willing to output this or not , but you can give it a try.

Comment: yes, this is what i mean. i'm so sorry if i can't explain it well. my english is not so good. thank u, thank u so much. @Lekhnath